How to make delayed arrival of tooltips in jetpack compose?
I am using ToolTipBox and tooltip, they work fine, i can customize the appearance, but the tooltips show up too fast, so when i`m hovering over the row of buttons it looks like crazy slideshow. I want tooltips to wait a little before appearing. How can i do it?
I tried to add some animations and effects to make tooltips appear slowly, but didn`t succeed.
